# Flutter AnimatedBuilder don't update the view

Tags: flutter, animation

I created a simple loading bar with a CustomPainter. It works well and i added an animation when i change the value of the bar.

[image]

The problem is that the visual update of the animation stop only after some milliseconds. I can see in the console that the animation controller value continue to change but there is no more update on the screen.

```
AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _animationController,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return CustomPaint(
        painter: BarPainter(
          color: widget.color,
          percent: _animationController.value,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

If i add an extra text showing the animation value, the animation works normally.

```
AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _animationController,
    builder: (context, child) {
      print(_animationController.value);
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Text(_animationController.value.toString()),
          CustomPaint(
            painter: BarPainter(
              color: widget.color,
              percent: _animationController.value,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
```

Anybody have encountered this weird behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it was simply to return true from the shouldRepaint method in the Painter code.

```
@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return true;
}
```